# Displaying block only when user visits his own profile page

Tags: blocks

I want to display the block only when the current user visits own page.
So in block visibility I use the following PHP:

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid == arg(1)) {;
return TRUE;
} else {;
return FALSE;
};
endif;
```

But that block returns on every page.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By own page you mean user profile page?

Comment: yes own profile page which is normally located on domain.com/en/user/#  , although I have set it to display as domain.com/en/username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the php code in the block visibility option than I guess the following should work:

```
<?php
global $user;
$user_id = $user->uid;
if (('user' === arg(0)) && ($user_id === arg(1))) {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

If your site is multi-lingual than may be you have to change the if condition as: `if (('user' === arg(1)) && ($user_id === arg(2)))`

Comment: If user on edit profile this section is also displaying.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is insufficient, as it does not check whether the user is editing their account (user/uid/edit), or simply viewing it (user/uid or user/uid/view).

```
<?php
$uid = $GLOBALS['user']->uid;
if ('user' == arg(0) && $uid == arg(1) && ('view' == arg(2) || NULL == arg(2))) {
  return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
?>
```

The above code ensures that your block will ONLY ever be visible when the user account is being viewed (at /user/uid or /user/uid/view) by the user the account belongs to.

Personally, I would simply use Views to create a page, which uses a contextual filter that uses the currently logged-in user to display specific information about them.